# How to change the xubuntu scroll bar?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, scrollbar

How to change the XUbuntu scroll bar?

[image]
I have looked in various forums, and found nothing about. I've tried the command:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.desktop.interface scrollbar-mode normal
```

But it did not work.

About the system is Ubuntu 04.16 with Unity. Xfce installed with the command:

```
apt install xubuntu-core^
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?